# Multiple permission to view/add/change a model class object

Tags: django

I am trying to edit permissions from the admin-site for a specific group in my project. (Specifically the Manager group)
I noticed that for this one model class named DeliveryOrderForm, contains two instances of one permission.
For example :

deliveryorder| delivery order form | can add delivery order form

deliveryorder| delivery order form | can add delivery order

What I understand is that the first part 'deliveryorder' is referencing the application name, the second part is referencing the model's class name, but I am unsure what the 3rd part is referencing to.

These are the attributes for my class DeliveryOrderForm model

```
class DeliveryOrderForm(models.Model):
    deliveryOrderID = models.AutoField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    vendorName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    vendorAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recipientName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    recipientPhone = PhoneNumberField(blank=False)
    recipientAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deliveryOrderStatus = models.IntegerField(default=Status.pending,choices=Status.choices)
    deliveryOrderDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

I hope someone can help me understand this cause I'm afraid if my model is actually screwed up.

Edit : Turns out, the old permissions retained after I renamed the model class from DeliveryOrder (previous class name) to DeliveryOrderForm (current class name). Removing the old permissions should solve this.

Comment: Did you change the name of the model at some point?

Comment: I think I did earlier in the project , something like from class DeliveryOrder to (now) class DeliveryOrderForm. I also think I makemigrations/migrate during both instances.

Comment: When you change the name of a model new permissions are created with the new name but the old permissions with the previous name are not removed. You could manually remove the old permissions...

Comment: I see .. I guess I'm going to have to search of ways to remove it now. Thanks for your help! @IainShelvington